# How to work with Dropbox Paper TODOs via API?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have gone through the API documentation on the Dropbox website, and have found the section that relates to Paper, however I don't see a way to work with the TODO's for a document or a user.
Is this something that is not yet supported or have I missed it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to interact with Paper to-do items unfortunately, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. May I ask, how frequent are the updates to the API ? Is it worth holding my breath ?

Comment: @PeterAndreasMoelgaard Unfortunately I can't offer any firm timeline of if/when this might be implemented, but right now I'm not aware of any work on this.